# R: position element x[m]>value for which all subsequent elements i>m also x[i]>value

Tags: r

on the forum I found the `?which()` command and applied it on a vector containing a sequence of time indexed values as follows:

```
first.element <- which(e>0)[1]
```

to find the first element for which `e!=0` but now I want to be sure that also all subsequent elements are `>0` cos I'm not searching for the first element `e>0` but for the first elemtn 'e>0' for which also all subsequent elements in the vector are larger than 0.

Usually search on the internet sooner or later delivers the proper code but this time I wasn't successful. If one of you knows a solution I'd be very thankful.

BR

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just reverse the vector and find the first 0?

```
which(rev(e)<=0)[1]
```

Comment: I think maybe you meant `<= 0`? And wouldn't finding the last value less than 0 in the original order be equivalent...?

Comment: Señor O, that's a really simple but quite smart solution to my problem.

Thank you